# Why is daltoniam Skeets proposing NSDocumentDirectory as location for cache files

Tags: ios, swift, caching

In the documentation of Skeets, an image loader / cache framework written in swift for iOS / MacOS, one example shows how to specify the cache path.

```
//set the cache directory. Only have to do this once since `sharedManager` is a singleton
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
ImageManager.sharedManager.cache.diskDirectory = "\(paths[0])/ImageCache"
```

My understanding until now was, that the Document Directory (and its subdirectories) is NOT the right choice to store cache data, it even leads to failing the app review process, due to the fact, that the Document Directory gets backed up to the iCloud and cache data is nothing, which we really want to back up in the cloud.

Unless of course we exclude the Directory, which we specified, from the iCloud backup explicitly.

I thought the NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory would be the appropriate location to store cache data?

Comment: You are probably right. Maybe report this as a bug to Skeets.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, just added an issue to the Skeets Github page. I will come back here and post the authors answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been a Github issue, was made into a Github issue, and was [fixed](https://github.com/daltoniam/Skeets/issues/13) some time ago.